# Call SQL stored procedure from VBA - ADO - Named Parameters

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures, ado

Experimenting with VBA ADO with below code to call a stored procedure (with three parameters @p1, @p2, @p3) that writes data to an SQL table (with three columns p1,p2,p3).

Despite having NamedParameters set to true, the parameter names, though populated in the Parameter object, seemingly do not feed through to SQL, i.e. in the SQL table I get < p1,p2,p3> = <7,8,9> instead of <7,9,8>.

```
Sub UploadShareclassDatatoDB()
Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim ADODBCmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

NamedParameters = True

Dim i As Integer
Dim sConnect As String

sConnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User ID=**;Password=**;Initial Catalog=**;Data Source=**;"

Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
Conn.ConnectionString = sConnect
Conn.Open

Set ADODBCmd = New ADODB.Command
ADODBCmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
ADODBCmd.CommandText = "test"
ADODBCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

ADODBCmd.Parameters.Append ADODBCmd.CreateParameter("@p1", adInteger, adParamInput, , 7)
ADODBCmd.Parameters.Append ADODBCmd.CreateParameter("@p3", adInteger, adParamInput, , 8)
ADODBCmd.Parameters.Append ADODBCmd.CreateParameter("@p2", adInteger, adParamInput, , 9)

Set rs = ADODBCmd.Execute()

End Sub
```

What do I need to do so the procedure is invoked with parameters depending on parameter name rather than the order in which the parameters are constructed by the code?

Comment: Surely you need some sql with the parameters in it somewhere? I would assume that would be here `ADODBCmd.CommandText = "test"` so replace `test` with something like `test(?,?,?)`. Also, I could be wrong but I don't think ado in VBA supports named parameters, they just appear in the order you call `DODBCmd.Parameters.Append ADODBCmd.CreateParameter`. See    https://stackoverflow.com/q/17597485/1011724 for example

Comment: I want to pass named parameters to the procedure, which is why I'm using the CreateParameter Method.

Comment: Yes, if you look at the link I posted you'll see it also uses the `CreateParameter` method. What I'm saying is that those are not named parameters in the sense that sql-server will match the names to parameter names in a query. It just uses them in order and you put a `?` in your query where you want to use a parameter. One `?` per parameter in the order you added them.

Comment: @Dan - Apparently ADO 2.6 and later is supposed to support named parameters and when I step through the code it seems to perform as expected. I've also read suggestions, though that OLEDB does not support named parameters, so this might be the issue here.

Comment: My workaround for the moment is this:                `ADODBCmd.Parameters.Refresh
    ADODBCmd.Parameters("@p3").Value = 4
    ADODBCmd.Parameters("@p1").Value = 6
    ADODBCmd.Parameters("@p2").Value = 10`